# c++ error inheriting baseClass with template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've a question about an error I get by inherenting a template base class. I get this error in my subclass source file:

```
error: class ‘JobCalcReturn’ does not have any field named ‘JobMaster’
```

my base class as a *.h file:

```
template<class dataIn, class dataOut>
class JobMaster
{
public:
   JobMaster() : JSONin("NOP"){};
   JobMaster(const std::string &_JSONin) :  JSONin(_JSONin){};
   virtual ~JobMaster(){};
private:
   static dataIn dataInObject;
   static dataOut dataOutObject;
   const  std::string &JSONin;
   static std::string JSONout;
   virtual std::string dataInHandler(dataIn&  dataInObject){...};
   //Some more virutal methodes
};
```

my subclass header:

```
class DataInClass{...};

class JobCalcReturn :public JobMaster<DataInClass, Poco::JSON::Array>
{
public:
   JobCalcReturn(const std::string &_JSONin);
   ~JobCalcReturn();
private:
    std::string dataInHandler(DataInClass& calcRatrunData); 
};
```

my subclass source file:

```
JobCalcReturn::JobCalcReturn(const std::string& _JSONin) : JobMaster(_JSONin){}
//here in the constructor i get the error
JobCalcReturn::~JobCalcReturn(){}

std::string JobCalcReturn::dataInHandler(DataInClass& calcRatrunData){...}
```

I wrote this with Visual Studio 2013 and got no error, then I switch the system to Linux with eclipse and the gcc c++ compieler and I get this error. Does someone has a clue why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

`Jobmaster` is a class template. So you need to provide the template arguments in the `JobCalcReturn` constructor's definition:

```
JobCalcReturn::JobCalcReturn(const std::string& _JSONin) 
: JobMaster<DataInClass, Poco::JSON::Array>(_JSONin){}
```

Also note that `_JSONin` is a [***reserved identifier***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). You need to use a different name.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza for the hint with the reserved identifier, but i tryed this and get a new error in the header file:
`error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token`
in this line:
`class JobCalcReturn :public JobMaster<CalcReturnDataInClass, Poco::JSON::Array>`
Isn't JobMaster my template-name?